# C# Remove An Empty Character Array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

I have character arrays seperated into multiple groups, my code uses a character from every group, so once character in a group is processed it will go to the next. I want to remove a group when it's considered empty. (or alternative if you can help fix the code so it skips empty groups)

In the form, there are checkboxes which add the specific characters to their specified group, you have the option to add those characters of choice or not, which I also have a user include input textbox if they want to add their personal characters, but in a case of a char group being empty I get an exception most likely due to the group having no characters.

Exception:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the
> array."

For

> "result[i] = charGroups[nextGroupIdx][nextCharIdx];"

```
                char[][] charGroups = new char[][]
                {
                    CapitalCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    LowercaseCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    NumbersCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    IncludeCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    SpecialCharacterSet.ToCharArray()
                };
```

FULL CODE:

```
                char[][] charGroups = new char[][]
                {
                    CapitalCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    LowercaseCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    NumbersCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    IncludeCharacterSet.ToCharArray(),
                    SpecialCharacterSet.ToCharArray()
                };

                int[] charsLeftInGroup = new int[charGroups.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < charsLeftInGroup.Length; i++)
                    charsLeftInGroup[i] = charGroups[i].Length;

                int[] leftGroupsOrder = new int[charGroups.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < leftGroupsOrder.Length; i++)
                    leftGroupsOrder[i] = i;

                byte[] randomBytes = new byte[4];

                RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new();
                rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

                int seed = BitConverter.ToInt32(randomBytes, 0);

                Random random = new(seed);

                char[] result = null;

                result = new char[length.Value];

                int nextCharIdx;

                int nextGroupIdx;

                int nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx;

                int lastCharIdx;

                int lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx = leftGroupsOrder.Length - 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx == 0)
                        nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx = 0;
                    else
                        nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx = random.Next(0, lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx);

                    nextGroupIdx = leftGroupsOrder[nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx];

                    lastCharIdx = charsLeftInGroup[nextGroupIdx] - 1;

                    if (lastCharIdx == 0)
                        nextCharIdx = 0;
                    else
                        nextCharIdx = random.Next(0, lastCharIdx + 1);

                    try
                    {
                        result[i] = charGroups[nextGroupIdx][nextCharIdx];
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        if (lastCharIdx == 0)
                            nextCharIdx = 0;
                        else
                            nextCharIdx = random.Next(0, lastCharIdx + 1);
                    }

                    if (lastCharIdx == 0)
                        charsLeftInGroup[nextGroupIdx] = charGroups[nextGroupIdx].Length;
                    else
                    {
                        if (lastCharIdx != nextCharIdx)
                        {
                            char temp = charGroups[nextGroupIdx][lastCharIdx];
                            charGroups[nextGroupIdx][lastCharIdx] =
                                        charGroups[nextGroupIdx][nextCharIdx];
                            charGroups[nextGroupIdx][nextCharIdx] = temp;
                        }
                        charsLeftInGroup[nextGroupIdx]--;
                    }

                    if (lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx == 0)
                        lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx = leftGroupsOrder.Length - 1;

                    else
                        if (lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx != nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx)
                        {
                            int temp = leftGroupsOrder[lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx];
                            leftGroupsOrder[lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx] =
                                        leftGroupsOrder[nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx];
                            leftGroupsOrder[nextLeftGroupsOrderIdx] = temp;
                        }

                        lastLeftGroupsOrderIdx--;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This would be a great time to familiarize yourself with the debugger. Set a breakpoint on that line and see what values you're working with. With an exception like this the issue is usually pretty obvious.

Comment: It seems you'll have to guard for `charsLeftInGroup == 0`, skipping the group if this is true.

Comment: can you provide an example, I'm a visual learner and quick to understand something when presented to me. I've never took any classes or learned from code from anyone so everything I've learned has been self-taught.

Comment: result = new char[length.Value]; What does “length” refer to in this line of code? You'd better set up a breakpoint to check the code first, please refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019

Comment: length.Value refers to the password length, it doesn't have anything to do with the issue, i'm fully aware of the issue of the code but I don't know how I can fix it, the code will use a character out of each character array group will cycle through and go to the next character array group, and once it gets to an character array group which is empty, it will cause an exception when the character array group does not have any characters.

Comment: the code was initially took from https://github.com/obviex/Samples/blob/master/Password.md

Comment: What will/should happen if the desired password length is greater the the number of all charachters in all groups? If I understand the algorithm correctly, the idea is to use every character of every group not more than one time.